# Connection power BI report to SSAS fails

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssas, power-bi-report-server, analysisservices

I published on power BI report server a template connected to SQL server analysis services tabular model , I try to enter credentials and to impersonate the user but it never works and give an error as describe in image.
I have power bi server and pwer bi services on different instances not same server.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOuOq.png)

should i do any more configurations?